# how to use pointer of one namespace in another namespace nad both the namespace are used in another class

Tags: c++11, namespaces

Below is my sample code where we are facing the issue

### file1.h

```
namespace name1
{
    extern name1::test* _test;
}
```

### file2.h

```
namespace name2
{
    class toolbox
    {
        int fun()
        {
            return _test->test();
        }
    }
}
```

### newfile.cpp

```
using namespace name1;
using namespace name2;

int newclass::new()
{
    return _test->test();
}
```

With above I will get error :
undefined reference to name2::_test

If I add extern in name2 I get error :
_test ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have are conflicting symbols between the namespaces that you are using.
This is a typical example used in styleguides which forbid `using namespace`.

Instead of including the whole namespace, you could prefix the identifiers with `NS::`, for example: `name1::_test`.

Alternatively, it is possible to selectively use elements from the namespace by using: `using NS::Identifier`. However, I never found myself in a situation where I needed on a global, so don't know if this works.

A piece of advice: don't use global variables, it is much more maintainable to pass the pointers or references as arguments for your functions.